# How to make unicode show in desktop view

Tags: html, css

I have several unicodes which show in mobile but not desktop.

I'm assuming I can't force an @media query.

Html snipped:

```html
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard- 
    2/awpcp-reply-to-ad/21/old-goriot-balzac/">
  <div class="email"><span><center>&#x1F4E7</center>. 
    </span></div>
</a>
<a href="tel:<br/><label>Phone: 
    </label> 07576335122">
  <div class="phone"><span>. 
    <center>&#128222</center></span></div>
</a>
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=:<br/>. 
    <label>Location:</label> Westminster, London, UK">
  <div class="location"><span><center>&#x1F4CD</center>. 
     </span></div>
</a>
```

This is original source code:

```
<div id="showawpcpadpage"> <div class="awpcp- 
title">$ad_title</div><br/> <div 
class="showawpcpadpage"> $featureimg <div 
class="awpcp-subtitle">Contact Information</div> <a 
href="$codecontact"><div class="email"><span>. 
<center>&#x1F4E7</center></span></div></a><a 
href="tel:$adcontactphone"><div class="phone"><span>. 
<center>&#128222</center></span></div></a> <a 
href="maps.google.com/?q=:$location"><div 
class="location"><span><center>&#x1F4CD</center>. 
</span></div></a> <div class="visit-website"><Visit 
Website:</div> $awpcpvisitwebsite </div>
```

This is entire code governing page layout.

```
 <div id="showawpcpadpage">
 <div class="awpcp-title">$ad_title</div><br/>
 <div class="showawpcpadpage">
 $featureimg


 <div class="awpcp-subtitle">Contact Information</div>


<a href="$codecontact"><div class="email"><span>. 
<center>&#x1F4E7</center></span></div></a><a 
href="tel:$adcontactphone"><div class="phone"><span>. 
<center>&#128222</center></span></div></a>
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=:$location"><div 
class="location"><span><center>&#x1F4CD</center>. 
 </span></div></a>

 <div class="visit-website"><Visit Website:</div>
 $awpcpvisitwebsite

   </div>
  $aditemprice
  $awpcpextrafields
  <div class="fixfloat"></div>
  $showadsense1
  <div class="showawpcpadpage">
  <div class="awpcp-subtitle">More Information</div>
  $addetails
  </div>
  $showadsense2
  <div class="fixfloat"></div>
  <div id="displayimagethumbswrapper">
  <div id="displayimagethumbs">
  <ul>
  $awpcpshowadotherimages
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  <span class="fixfloat">$tweetbtn $sharebtn 
  $flagad</span>
  $awpcpadviews
  $showadsense3
  $edit_listing_link
  </div>
```

That's all the code i have and it controls entire layout. Do you think there might be something to modify there to stop this br label stuff in location?

Comment: Close your hrefs too

Comment: Thanks. Well noticed

Comment: Where is `:$location` coming from? Some framework?

Comment: Not sure. It's part of a plugin...

Comment: But it's governed also by user input. Each location is different of course depending on what user enters. But user never enters br label etc and still it shows...

Comment: I really have to pull every bit of info out but by bit here? WHAT plugin running WHERE? Sever or client???

Comment: So it's  a wordpress site. The plugin is a plugin on that WordPress site

Comment: It controls everything about the classifieds posting system

Comment: Great - so do you need it or does the code I posted not do what you need?

Comment: Site is https://www.adsler.co.uk if that helps

Comment: I’m on my phone now. I do not do anything with wp plugins

Comment: I don't know how to implement it. If i go into my html source files through cpanel the html posted originally doesn't show. Only :$adcontactphone' etc shows.

Comment: Ok. No problem. Thanks for your time anyway. Cheers

Comment: I do not see anything on your site that looks like the code you posted

Comment: I know. It's weird. The html shown on site differs to html shown when i look at files in my file Manger through cpanel. I'm not knowledgeable enough to know why or how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better formatting. Your HTML was a mess with unclosed quotes and other horrors

Note that due to sandboxing you will need to open the Google map link in a new window using right mouse

```css
a { text-decoration:none }
```

```html
<a href="mailto@aaa.bbb.com">
  <span class="email">&#x1F4E7</span> Email: aaa@bbb.com
</a><br/>
<a href="tel:99999999">
  <span class="phone">&#128222</span>
  <label>Phone:</label> 999999999
</a><br/>
<a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=Westminster,London,UK" target="_blank">
  <span class="location">&#x1F4CD</span>
  <label>Location:</label> Westminster, London, UK
</a>
```

I see this in Chrome

[image]

Comment: Yes, phone and email correct because you need to log in to access. Location in Internet explorer and on mobile comes up as ': br/  label Location: /label  Westminster, London, UK'

Comment: If you run my code and right click open in new window?

Comment: And in apple safari, i when i click on phone icon. It then says can't dial br<label>, hone<label> 07945xxxx because not a valid number. In android works fine for phone but Google maps still displaying 'br/ label Location: /label Westminster, London, UK' in android, Chrome, Safari, Firefox. Google maps adjusts itself by ignoring irrelevant requests but still, how get rid of it?

Comment: Shown htm is a result of this <div id="showawpcpadpage">
<div class="awpcp-title">$ad_title</div><br/>
<div class="showawpcpadpage">
$featureimg


<div class="awpcp-subtitle">Contact Information</div>


<a href="$codecontact"><div class="email"><span><center>&#x1F4E7</center></span></div></a><a href="tel:$adcontactphone"><div class="phone"><span><center>&#128222</center></span></div></a>
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=:$location"><div class="location"><span><center>&#x1F4CD</center></span></div></a>

<div class="visit-website"><Visit Website:</div>
$awpcpvisitwebsite

</div>

Comment: So :$location contains html and other stuff

Comment: So id need to change this somehow and insert it in my html box. It's part of a plugin you see. Basically, i just need location to stop doing br label etc. How to modify that with above source code?

Comment: I have no idea - you did not post that part. If you cannot modify it, you would need to wrap it in something and run some regex or so - not recommended. Show mor relevant code IN THE QUESTION - don’t post code in comments

Comment: Ok. Done that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They do show on desktop. It just depends if the device has support for emoji.

Make sure to remove text decoration from them so that there's no blue hyperlinks.

Alternatively you can use something like emoji CSS.

Add `<link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">` to your head and then link them as an i class `<i class="em em-airplane"></i>` Please see [here](https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css) for a list of all supported emoji. You then don't need to worry about device support. I'd recommend better formatting your HTML so that it's more readable.

`Update`

[image: Before & After]

Just make sure to turn off text decoration if you link like that. Using emojicss isn't going to require you remove them.

`<a href="https://flights.google.com"><i class="em em-airplane"></i></a>` will take the user to google flights once they click the aeroplane.

```html
<link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
<div id=links>
<a href="#maillink"> <i class="em em-email"></i> Email hello@example.com</a><br>
<a href="#phonelink"> <i class="em em-phone"></i> Phone 0000 000 0000</a><br>
<a href="#pinlink"> <i class="em em-pushpin"></i> London, UK</a><br>
</div>

<style>
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

Make sure to turn off text decoration for links.

Comment: Thanks. What's a blue hyperlink please?

Comment: The desktop I tried it on was a brand new laptop with Internet explorer though. How can that not have emoji support?

Comment: It depends on the OS version and they may not be enabled. Please see the update to the question and use Emoji CSS instead as it's more reliable. I'd recommend testing in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. IE isn't supported anymore and Edge is moving to Chromium soon.

Comment: Thanks. What is text decoration please?

Comment: Text decoration is the underline on a link, text or image.

Comment: Ok. And how to remove text decoration? Im confused though. It didn't work in Safari which presumably has emoji support?

Comment: So basically the only way of doing it is a) using device/browser with emoji support or b) using i class?

Comment: Please see the new answer update, I've provided a full example. Just change the links as you need them to be then click the tick next to the answer I've provided.

Comment: And I also have another question of you're up for it? Clicking on my 'location' link brings up code 'br>label' and then actual location. How do I stop this please?

Comment: Edit your question and add a new snippet with the links in place, copy the snippet from my answer and I'll look

Comment: @Ads you had unclosed hrefs. Have a look at my reformatting of your actual code

Comment: Take a look at the answer update, I've added text. Just copy, paste and then add the links and text that you want.

Comment: IE not supported by what anymore?

Comment: By Microsoft. Have you sorted this with the newest snippet that I added?